c++ efficient explicit template instantiation for several template parameters
I am writing a c++ library where I deal with plenty of templated classes and free functions . Example (header + source file containing a free function):
#ifndef MY_FUNCTION_HPP
#define MY_FUNCTION_HPP

#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned int dim, typename NumberType>
void process_data(const std::array<std::vector<NumberType>, dim>& data,
                  std::map<std::string, std::array<NumberType, dim>>& results);

#endif // MY_FUNCTION_HPP

// my_function.cc
#include "my_function.hpp"

// Implementation of the template function
template <unsigned int dim, typename NumberType>
void process_data(const std::array<std::vector<NumberType>, dim>& data,
                  std::map<std::string, std::array<NumberType, dim>>& results)
{}

// Explicit instantiations for dim = 2 and dim = 3, and NumberType = double
template void process_data<2, double>(const std::array<std::vector<double>, 2>&, 
                                      std::map<std::string, std::array<double, 2>>&);
template void process_data<3, double>(const std::array<std::vector<double>, 3>&, 
                                      std::map<std::string, std::array<double, 3>>&);

The function may have different template parameters (here dimand NumberType) which I want to instantiate for fixed values (dim=2and dim=3and NumberType = double). It is tedious to do this manually by hand and blows up the source files if there is a bunch of free functions with many parameters and classes to instantiate.
There are similar questions, e.g. here, but I am looking for a generic solution where

The function parameters are arbitrary data types (depending on the template parameter) and
the functions depend on one or more template parameters.

I also read about Boost.preprocessor, but I am not sure if it is applicable here.

If you move your definition to the header file the compiler will be able to implicitly instantiate the template for all valid calls for you, thus removing the need to be explicit.

@NathanOliver I follow the strategy of separating the code in header and source files. And I would like to stick to this.

With templates its hard to do that, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?r=Saves_AllUserSaves.  FWIW having all template code in the header file is the way most template code is handled.

"I am looking for a generic solution where (1) The function parameters are arbitrary data types (depending on the template parameter)" - It sounds like you actually want exactly what @NathanOliver mentioned. Why make it hard for yourself? If you want separation, make the header file include another header file where the implementations are put.

@NathanOliver I see. But there are for sure good reasons to make the separation between header and source file. In that case, are there no common facilitation techniques for the explicit instantiation (e.g macros, boost,...)?

Nope, the technique is to move the code into the header file and the compiler will do the work for you or you have to manually instantiate the template for every combination you want to allow.  At best you could probably leverage a macro to handle all the boilerplate but you still need N macro calls for the N definitions you want to allow.

@Mathieu there are indeed good reasons for separating header and source files for non-template code. But for templates it's usually not the case. See the post NatanOliver mentioned above (Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?).

@wohlstad So I can keep my .cc file and .hpp, but include the .cc file (without explicit inst.) at the end of the .hpp file? Is that the way to go?

@Mathieu Sort of - just don't call it a .cc file since that confuses people. It will not be a translation unit of its own. You can do it as I mentioned already. Have the header file include another header file.

@Ted Lyngmo? Why not calling it .cc? What is better?

@Mathieu Because it will not be a file that is compiled as a translation unit. There are different conventions for naming such files, such as .inl, .ipp ...

One "common" way to do it is name it a .tpp file and include it at the end of the header file.

I see. But the drawback of this approach is most likely lager compilation times right?

in theory you may have more implicit instantiations since each TU gets its own set of instantiations so multiple TU's may produce the same instantiation.  How much this will really cost I feel is very minimal since you aren't doing recursive template or TMP which tends to generate lots of instantiations.

Say I have 10 templated classes (10 .h files). Currently, I have 10 .cc files (including explicit Inst.) which I compiled individually and wrapper in a library. With the .tpp solution I would not compile these 10 files anymore. So I can still build my own library?

If all of your library is templates, then you won't compile anything yourself. Your library will be a header-only library, which is valid and common for templated code. If you're worried about compilation times you might look into c++ 20 modules, but be warned: even now they're still pretty cutting edge in terms of compiler support.


The function may have different template parameters (here dimand NumberType) which I want to instantiate for fixed values (dim=2and dim=3and NumberType = double).

In that case, you might expose in header only the non template overloads:
#ifndef MY_FUNCTION_HPP
#define MY_FUNCTION_HPP

#include <array>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void process_data(const std::array<std::vector<double>, 2>&, 
                  std::map<std::string, std::array<double, 2>>&);
void process_data(const std::array<std::vector<double>, 3>&, 
                  std::map<std::string, std::array<double, 3>>&);

#endif // MY_FUNCTION_HPP

And then in source file:
#include "my_function.hpp"

namespace {
// Implementation of the template function
template <unsigned int dim, typename NumberType>
void process_data_impl(const std::array<std::vector<NumberType>, dim>& data,
                  std::map<std::string, std::array<NumberType, dim>>& results)
{
    //...
}

}

void process_data(const std::array<std::vector<double>, 2>& a, 
                  std::map<std::string, std::array<double, 2>>& m)
{
    process_data_impl(a, m);
}
void process_data(const std::array<std::vector<double>, 3>& a, 
                  std::map<std::string, std::array<double, 3>>& m)
{
    process_data_impl(a, m);
}


But that does not seem to be less effort in terms of lines to code.  What you write in the Header file is sort of what one would write for the explicit instantiation in the source file, is not it?

It is indeed similar, but have some advantages: - transform linker errors with mismatching type (as 4, double) to build error (no overloads found). - Allow to use initializer_list and conversion as the arguments are no longer template.

Viable alternative would be to have definition in header (as suggested in comment), potentially in dedicated header file (.inl, .tpp, .icc, ...)
